# Byte-level versus file-level backups

Tags: backup

This question is motivated from [a reply by Craig Sanders](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47767/23153). Thanks, Craig!

In what case, are byte or block level backups, i.e. disk or partition image backups, more suitable than file-based backups?

For example,

- for routine backup of partitions and disks,
- for case of emergency when data is lost, and one would like to create a copy and restore later, in order to perform different data recovery applications/methods to see which one actually works.

One example of byte or block level backups, i.e. disk or partition image backups is `dd`.

Some examples of file-based backups are `cp` and `rsync`.

Thanks!

Comment: Disk images are mostly useful for BMR (bare metal restore). In Linux you can typically BMR with file backups, but not as easily.

Comment: In my opinion, the file-based are better. When you lost the half of your backup, it's easiest recover the other half with a backup system based on files. But jordanm is right with the backups of bare-metal.

Answer (score 2):

Any instance when information outside of the file system needs to be saved. I can think of two instances:

- As mentioned in the comments, bare metal restores when the boot sector and partition table need to be saved so an exact copy of a server can be created.
- Some databases can be configured to write to a raw partition and not use a file system